# Python script runs when used inside IDE, but doesn't run outside

Tags: python, pandas

Trying to run the following:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('FILE', sep='\t')
df.drop(df.columns[[20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26]], axis=1, inplace=True)
print(df)
print(df.columns.values)
df.to_csv('FILE_CLEANED', sep='\t', encoding='utf-8', index=False)
```

I can run this out of Pycharm no problem, file is read and a new file is saved with the appropriate name, however I am trying to schedule this Task Scheduler to run daily. When I click on the .py file to run it (have also tried .pyw), terminal pops up, but nothing actually happens.

Any ideas?

NB: I'm running another script via targeting in task scheduler that is running properly (a download from FTP server), that is running no problem.

Comment: Clicking it may indeed run the py file - it all depends on your system - but running it within a terminal (eg cmd prompt) will mean that you can read any error message that gets produced

Comment: When Task Scheduler runs a program,  it does not necessarily have the same working directory that is set in PyCharm. If your input filename has a relative path then the program is probably failing with a file not found error. The same goes for clicking the filename in Explorer. Open a Windows console and run your program from the console prompt.  Then you will at least see the error message.